# Paperclip setup nightmare. advice?

Tags: paperclip

We have projects and photos in separate tables and models. Here is our schema:

```
 create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
    t.string   "description"
    t.boolean  "retired",         default: false
    t.integer  "tenant_id"
    t.date     "requested_by"
    t.integer  "repayment_rate"
    t.date     "repayment_begin"
  end



 create_table "photos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "project_id"
  end
```

In the project model I have:

```
has_attached_file :image
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]
```

Is this acceptable as a way to setup paperclip? Or do projects and photos have to be all in one table?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's acceptable, but your `has_attached_file` and `validates_attachment_content_type` must be into **photos** model, not into project model.

```
# project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end

# photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_attached_file :image #, styles: { svga: ["800x600!", :jpg], big: ["500x375!", :jpg], small: ["190x143!", :jpg], thumb: ["95x71!", :jpg] }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"] # or do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end
```